# How to access Userdefault in different View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, data-persistence

I am planning to save users' preference setting in Userdefalut, the problem is the user's preference setting will be edited in View Controller A, and View Controller B and View Controller C need to read it.
I understand that I can make an instance like

```
var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

My plan is put it in AppDelegate, so how can I access it from Other View Controller if it is in AppDelegate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you do not require to put it in `AppDelgate` as you're not creating an object every time. Instead, you're using it's shared instance (singleton) so you will always have the same `userDefaults` objects in all of your view controller.

Comment: That makes a lot sense